# Transfer USDC from one wallet address to another address

Tags: spl-token, transfer, spl-token-program, stablecoins, usdc

I'm new to SOL.

I've been reading [this](https://www.0xdev.co/how-to-transfer-tokens-on-solana-javascript/) and [this](https://spl.solana.com/token#example-transferring-tokens-to-another-user) but there's no vanilla JS code. And [this](https://www.0xdev.co/how-to-transfer-tokens-on-solana-javascript/) actually mixes a lot of conditions - from knowing the wallet private key to transferring from a wallet connected to your site, etc.

Could someone show me how to transfer USDC from one wallet to another with a wallet already connected to my site (I've achieved this and my site is supporting Phantom)?

UPDATE
Here's what I have and it doesn't work as I get Transaction is not defined error

```
const transferTransaction = new Transaction()
.add(
    createTransferInstruction( // imported from '@solana/spl-token'
        "zGmof8SeyvHK3zZqsTBjsKXSV",
        "ErfpX6PMGUKdBWzUXqgZfbhrC4h4CWE",
        "zGmof8SeyvHKnSe85D3zZqsTBjsKXSV",
        parseInt(amount * Math.pow(10, 6)), // tokens have 6 decimals of precision so your amount needs to have the same
        [],
        "TokenkegQfeZBvf9Ss623VQ5DA" // imported from '@solana/spl-token'
    )
);

const network = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";
const connection = new Connection(network);
transferTransaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getRecentBlockhash()).blockhash;
transferTransaction.feePayer = alice.publicKey;
const { signature } = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(transferTransaction);
await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);

console.log(signature);
```

Comment: what framework you using?

Answer (score 2):

There's a guide in the [Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-spl-tokens) on how to send SPL-Tokens.

You need to the mint address of the SPL token you want to transfer to find the [associated token addresses](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-create-a-token-account).

```
import { createTransferInstruction, getAccount, getAssociatedTokenAddress, getMint } from '@solana/spl-token';

// Add token transfer instructions to transaction

// Get the sender's ATA
const senderATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(splToken, sender);

// Get the recipient's ATA
const recipientATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(splToken, recipient);

// Create an instruction to transfer SPL tokens
const ix = createTransferInstruction(
  senderATA,
  recipientATA,
  sender,
  amount,
  [],
);
```

Comment: I don't think the above is vanilla JS. But anyway, what is ATA? AssociatedTokenAddress? What is that?

Comment: And where you got your `splToken, sender` values from

Comment: What about this is not vanilla? This is vanilla JS. Link for AssociatedTokenAddress: https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-create-a-token-account

Comment: And how you calculated your `amount`? Do you do this - `parseInt(amount * Math.pow(10, 6)),`

Comment: Could you share the code you have already, that will be easier. And to clarify, the code here is vanilla JS also: https://spl.solana.com/token#example-transferring-tokens-to-another-user

Comment: Update your question to include the code you have already

Comment: I just posted my code but i don;t know what I'm doing.

Comment: Where you got your splToken, sender values from. What are the values for splToken and sender? Is sender the wallet address? If so, what is splToken?

Comment: Is token account like Ethereum's smart contract?

Comment: Btw, I'm not trying to create a new USDC contract. I just want to use the existing contract at TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA on devnet So do I need `const senderATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(splToken, sender);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138370/discussion-between-c-og-and-ratib90486).